# MariaDB : Trigger keeps getting syntax error after insert

Tags: mariadb

I have two tables. Table `vitamin` contains column `vitamin_name` and `price`. Table `vitamin_variety` contains columns `price_variety` and `price_variety_extreme`. I want to create an AFTER INSERT Trigger, that will insert the `price` of `vitamin` if the value of `vitamin_name` contains `extreme` into `price_variety_extreme` and not contains `extreme` into `price_variety` .

Here's what I mean if I insert this into `vitamin`, the price will be input into `vitamin_variety`

```
table = vitamin
+----------------+-------+
|  vitamin_name  | price |
+----------------+-------+
| extreme pill 1 |    10 |
| pill 1         |     5 |
| extreme pill 2 |    20 |
| pill 2         |    10 |
+----------------+-------+
 table = vitamin_variety
+---------------+-----------------------+
| price_variety | price_variety_extreme |
+---------------+-----------------------+
|             5 |                    10 |
|            10 |                    20 |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

my query keeps getting syntax error. it keeps saying

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 5

what's wrong?

```
create trigger vitamin_ain after insert on vitamin
for each ROW
if vitamin.vitamin_name like 'extreme%' then 
    update vitamin_variety 
    set price_variety_extreme = new.price_variety_extreme;
else if vitamin.vitamin_name not like 'extreme%' then 
    update vitamin_variety
    set price_variety = new.price_variety;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax issues, and other situations, but the conditions inside the trigger could look like the code below:

First, (not right or wrong) the `else if` *could* be simplified to an `else`. If the first condition finds extreme, there is no need to inverse check for `not like` extreme. (unless some strange requirement expects that handling)

Of course, feel free to keep the `else if` check as-is, if it makes more sense to you, but I used this code:

```
if new.vitamin_name like 'extreme%' then 
    update vitamin_variety 
    set price_variety_extreme = new.price;
else  
    update vitamin_variety
    set price_variety = new.price;
end if
```

The 'syntax issues':

1. In the if condition, change `vitamin.vitamin_name` to `new.vitamin`. Columns from trigger insert actions are referenced from `new`, not the table name.
2. If keeping your original `else if`, need to change the same `vitamin.vitamin_name` reference mentioned in item 1.
3. References `new.price_variety_extreme` and `new.price_variety` do not exist from the vitamin insert (these columns are not in vitamin), but `new.price` is, and the other `vitamin` columns.

The 'other situations':

- Without any rows already present in the `vitamin_variety` table, no update will occur, because there are not any rows to update. This situation will make it *seem as if the trigger is not working*, but there is nothing for the trigger to update.
- The desired output to `vitamin_variety` cannot be achieved with the current info. The update will set ALL columns of one or the other to the last inserted price, because there is no unique row reference. (no WHERE clause to limit what row(s) get updated)

Here's some sample interaction:

As the first other situation mentioned, there are no rows in the `vitamin_variety` table, so I added one:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin_variety (price_variety, price_variety_extreme) values (0, 0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from vitamin_variety;
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
| id | price_variety | price_variety_extreme |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |             0 |                     0 |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, with the trigger added to `vitamin`, inserted a couple of rows:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin( vitamin_name, price ) values ('pilly 5', 7);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin( vitamin_name, price ) values ('extreme pill 5', 3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)
```

Show those inserts:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from vitamin;
+----+----------------+-------+
| id | vitamin_name   | price |
+----+----------------+-------+
|  8 | pilly 5        |     7 |
|  9 | extreme pill 5 |     3 |
+----+----------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Show the triggered price updates to the `vitamin_variety` table:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from vitamin_variety;
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
| id | price_variety | price_variety_extreme |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |             7 |                     3 |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

=====

EDIT:

One possible way to achieve your goal, given this `vitamin_variety` table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `vitamin_variety` (
 `pill_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
 `price_variety` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `price_variety_extreme` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `pill_name` (`pill_name`)
);
```

Then changing the `vitamin` table trigger conditions to:

```
if new.vitamin_name like 'extreme%' then 
    insert into vitamin_variety (pill_name, price_variety_extreme)
    values (replace(new.vitamin_name, 'extreme ', ''), new.price) 
    on duplicate key update price_variety_extreme = new.price;
else  
    insert into vitamin_variety (pill_name, price_variety)
    values (new.vitamin_name, new.price)
    on duplicate key update price_variety = new.price;
end if
```

Then running insert SQL based on your original `vitamin` table details:

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin (vitamin_name, price) values ('extreme pill 1', 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin (vitamin_name, price) values ('pill 1', 5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin (vitamin_name, price) values ('extreme pill 2', 20);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into vitamin (vitamin_name, price) values ('pill 2', 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
```

Gives:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from vitamin_variety;
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
| pill_name | price_variety | price_variety_extreme |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
| pill 1    |             5 |                    10 |
| pill 2    |            10 |                    20 |
+-----------+---------------+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you so much Paul for the detail explanation, it helps me a lot. I appreciate your answer so much. Do you have any suggestion how can I do to get my desired result? I haven't get any more idea to achieve my desired output. Thanks Paul

Comment: Not sure at the immediate moment, but I get the general idea. One rows covers both `pill 1` prices, the other for both `pill 2` prices. Do rows already exist in the `vitamin_variety` table before those trigger updates? May be later tomorrow before I check back, nearly midnight in my TZ.

Comment: No there isn't, I only need to insert them to `vitamin_variety` based on their extremeness. Okay Paul, Thanks a lot for helping me. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Edited the answer to show one possible way to achieve the desired goal.